# How to call a code behind function in the aspx file in a server tag

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have a TabPanel whose HeaderText property I want to set using a code behind function
eg.

```
<asp:TabPanel ID="id" runat="server" HeaderText='<%= String.Format("{0}","some text") %>'>
```

I can't put the function call between the start and end tags because it is a TabPanel, but when I do the above I just get an empty header on the page.  I have also tried <%# %> (I am not sure of the difference between the two).

The String.Format is just an example, not the real function I am trying to call.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to set this control from the code behind?  That's generally preferable to using script-lets wherever it's feasible (and here it is).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know some attributes don't support inline syntax, and this might be one of them, unfortunately. The syntax looks okay, which makes me think that might be the case. To workaround this issue, just set the `HeaderText` in code-behind.

As for the difference between `<%= ... %>` and `<%# ... %>`, the latter is used strictly for databinding syntax:

```
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%# Eval("SomeValue") %>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

**EDIT**

There's actually an easier way that I didn't think of before. Just use the `HeaderTemplate` to set the column header text dynamically:

```
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <%# Eval("SomeHeaderValue") %>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%# Eval("SomeValue") %>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

Comment: ok, thanks, I'll keep looking for a bit but it appears that you're right about it not being supported, if nothing turns up I'll accept this as correct

Comment: Let me know if you find something. Otherwise, thanks for the tentative accept :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`HeaderText='<%# TabPanel_HeaderText %>'`

In Code behind

```
protected string TabPanel_HeaderText
{
    get { return String.Format("{0}","some text"); }
}
```

Comment: As James pointed out in his answer, `<%# ... %>` is data binding syntax. `<%= ... =>` is basically shorthand for `<% Response.Write("...") %>`. So if inline code blocks are allowed for `HeaderText`, it should work with `<%= ... =>`.